# min-width on button causes space to the right of it in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button, internet-explorer-9

I am currently investigating strange behavior of the `CSS` `min-width` property in Internet Explorer. I heard about bugs with the text alignment, using `min-width`. But this one is new to me.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><button>Einloggen</button></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

When I set `min-width` of the button to a value that would actually stretch the button a space to the right of it emerges/ the `td` gets wider. I only saw this behavior in IE. Checked with Opera, FF, Chrome and Safari, too.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNDUz/4/) showing containing an example.

Is this a known bug? And are there any workarounds?

Comment: checked with IE9. With older ones I couldn't use jsfiddle.

Comment: Well, there is IE10 as well. :-) In any case it's good to confirm IE version because the versions in current use are all so different in capabilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There does appear to be a strange issue at play here with Internet Explorer 9. It's interesting that versions 8 and 10 both render this demo properly, without issue.

That being said, with regards to IE9, I have found a workaround that seems to resolve the issue. My success was with using the pseudo-element `::before` as a fallback:

```css
/* For everybody but IE9 */
button {
    min-width: 200px;
}

/* For Internet Explorer 9 */
button::before {
    content: "" \9;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JNDUz/21/

While this *works*, it does result in a slightly wider button in Internet Explorer 10 (pseudo-element width + parent padding/margins). These hacks have no business in IE10, but it's difficult to isolate them in CSS alone to certain browsers. The `\9` trick can isolate this from non-IE browsers, but there's a better way:

```
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en-us" class="no-js ie9"><![endif]-->
```

By wrapping the HTML tag in a conditional comment, we can now target IE alone with our fix:

```
/* For Internet Explorer 9 */
.ie9 button::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to restrict `button::before` to IE9 somehow - the selector alone is valid and any browser supporting `::before` on buttons will insert it. In particular, removing the rule makes the button slightly less wide on Firefox.

Comment: @BoltClock Good point; adding the suffix `\9` isolates this from Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari, but the accumulative issue still exists for IE10. The best solution is to buffer the HTML element with an `.ie9` class via a conditional comment, and then augment this selector with that class.

Comment: thank you very much! Seems to be the best workaround. Unfortunately I couldn't made it work in my `ADF` skin, yet.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: If the `\9` hack must be used, you'll want to add that to `content: "";` instead to ensure that the pseudo-element doesn't even generate a box (defaults to `content: none`).

Comment: Although this works in more complex layouts even with the `.ie9` class it causes problems, I haven't managed to get it work in more complex layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Well that was little weird, it adds padding to the right of the button, but I managed to get the least space on right, by using this

```
button {
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: well, there is still space on the right, though it is smaller. But this would also affect buttons with longer text, which would then have no padding.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes You can pad the button, else you can use `padding: 0;`, that's the closest I've got

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not valid markup, but wrapping `Einloggen` word to div fixes the issue.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>
                <div>Einloggen</div>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNDUz/5/)

Comment: Again as with my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082135/min-width-on-button-causes-space-to-the-right-of-it-in-ie#comment39207267_16084890) this doesn't work in more complex layouts, it also probably doesn't help that I'm using `<input type="button">`.

Answer (score 0):

The workarounds above seem to work fine, but consider also that cellspacing and cellpadding are deprecated from the CSS/HTML spec. Perhaps the deprecated status has something to do with it.

Comment: Does it without them being specified. *Confirmed in IE9*.